# How to configure Secure WSS on my WebSocketSharp Server in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, websocket, wss

I have this code on my server:

```
  Public Shared Sub Start(Port As Integer)

            ws = New WebSocketServer(Port, True)

            Dim filename As String = "cert.pfx"
            Dim cert As New Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(filename, "pass123", Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet)

            With ws.SslConfiguration
                .ServerCertificate = cert
                .ClientCertificateRequired = False
                .CheckCertificateRevocation = False
                .ClientCertificateValidationCallback = Function() As Boolean
                                                           Return True
                                                       End Function
                .EnabledSslProtocols = Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12
            End With

            ws.AddWebSocketService(Of GameBehavior)("/Game")
            ws.Start()

        End Sub
```

The application runs without any errors. But when a client connects via wss, I get this error:

> 9/1/2022 6:08:54
> PM|Fatal|<>c__DisplayClass71_0.b__0:0|System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException:
> A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. --->
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: An unknown error occurred while
> processing the certificate

I get no error whatsoever when I start the same application in ws mode (without secure wss).

What am I doing wrong? How to proper configure WSS on WebSocketSharp Server?

Comment: Did you look at the inner exception?  Did you take any additional debugging steps (e.g. looking at local logging, looking at any of the http or https traffic, etc)?  I don't have any significant knowledge on this, I just know those were some of the things I looked at when I ran into authentication issues on a web connection.